# Debian: run php files with parser

Tags: php, parsing, debian, lenny

I'm trying to be able to run php scripts on my vps. I do have php5 installed but when I run the php file it says

```
/usr/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

so I typed `whereis php5`

and the output is:

`php5: /etc/php5 /usr/lib/php5 /usr/share/php5`

Question is: what do I do at this point to make a php file run?

the top of my php file, what should i have? `#!/etc/php5`?

Comment: Use `which php5` for finding the interpreter. It also can just be called `php` or `php-cgi` or `php-cli`. And it's not present if you have only the `mod_php` version installed.

Comment: @mario when i type `which php5` i get no output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you don't have it installed. The commandline or CGI version can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

Or `-cli` if it's only for console scripts, and you already have mod_php running for Apache.

Comment: I think it does not create a default symlink in the Debian package. The binary will be called `/usr/bin/php5-cgi`. It's only the `php5-cli` package which provides `/usr/bin/php5` sans extension.

Comment: ok so on top of my php file I'd like to run, I have `#!/usr/bin/php5-cgi` ?

Comment: Yes, that would do. For parity with the CLI version, you'd use `#!/usr/bin/php5-cgi -qC` however.

Comment: It works good execpt one thing; it gets stuck and displays a bunch of weird messages: http://pastebin.com/1Snn1egW  is it because I am using cli? should i use something else?

Comment: That's indeed odd. Never seen anything like that. Try installing the php5-cli package then alternatively.